# Unable to log in as root in Oracle Linux Docker container

Tags: linux, oracle, docker, containers, root

I am trying to edit some files in a docker container using 
    docker exec -it container_Id bash

I am able to access the Commad line and the files but i can't login as root 
user.I tried all these commands :

```
root@Linux-Vostro-3250:~# docker exec -it MS1 bash
[oracle@b1c48eff3e2e base_domain]$ yum install nano
Loaded plugins: ovl
ovl: Error while doing RPMdb copy-up:
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/rpm/Requirename'
You need to be root to perform this command.
[oracle@b1c48eff3e2e base_domain]$ su
bash: su: command not found
[oracle@b1c48eff3e2e base_domain]$ sudo
bash: sudo: command not found
[oracle@b1c48eff3e2e base_domain]$ su -
bash: su: command not found
[oracle@b1c48eff3e2e base_domain]$ su-
bash: su-: command not found
[oracle@b1c48eff3e2e base_domain]$
```

Can someone help me with thiss..

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`docker exec` supports a `-u / --user` option:

```
docker exec -it -u root MS1 bash
```

Source: [Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/)

Answer (score 1):

I had to include the `--workdir` flag when running an OL7 container

```
docker exec -it -u root -w /root  CONTAINER  /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Perform the following commands:

```
1. docker exec -it countainername bash
2. su - oracle
3. sqlplus
4. 
Username:"/ as sysdba"
Password:sys as sysdba
```